# Does foreach have else?

Tags: c#, foreach, if-statement, dbnull

I have foreach to show the result from myquery, it works when the result isnt null. and I want to know does the foreach have else? to take action when the result from myquery is null?

```
var rs = from cs in db.CsCustomers
                      from ai in db.ArInvoices
                      where cs.CustomerID == ai.CustomerID &&
                      ai.Kategori != null
                      orderby cs.Unit
                      select new
                      {
                          cs.CustomerID,
                          cs.Unit,
                          cs.Name
                      };

foreach (var r in rs)
{
     c = new TableCell();
     c.Text = r.CustomerID;
     c.RowSpan = jk;
     tr.Cells.Add(c);

     c = new TableCell();
     c.Text = r.Unit;
     c.RowSpan = jk;
     tr.Cells.Add(c);

     c = new TableCell();
     c.Text = r.Name;
     c.RowSpan = jk;
     tr.Cells.Add(c);

}
```

Comment: You might want to add a method to remove all that duplicate code `c = new TableCell();
     c.Text = r.CustomerID;
     c.RowSpan = jk;
     tr.Cells.Add(c);`

Comment: If you think about it.. that doesn't make much sense. Foreach, literally means "(do something) for every something in a collection of somethings". Answers given by the people below are "(do something) for every something in a collection of somethings where something isn't null".. hopefully that makes sense to you.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead no they don't, they check the somethingS collection for being null, and then does something else, not ever single something.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to put check first -

```
if(rs == null)
{}
else
{
  foreach.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No it does not have an else operator. You could wrap it in an `if else`

```
var rs = from cs in db.CsCustomers
                      from ai in db.ArInvoices
                      where cs.CustomerID == ai.CustomerID &&
                      ai.Kategori != null
                      orderby cs.Unit
                      select new
                      {
                          cs.CustomerID,
                          cs.Unit,
                          cs.Name
                      };
if(rs != null && rs.Any()) //for the .Count you have to add using System.Linq;
     foreach (var r in rs)
     {
          c = new TableCell();
          c.Text = r.CustomerID;
          c.RowSpan = jk;
          tr.Cells.Add(c);

          c = new TableCell();
          c.Text = r.Unit;
          c.RowSpan = jk;
          tr.Cells.Add(c);

          c = new TableCell();
          c.Text = r.Name;
          c.RowSpan = jk;
          tr.Cells.Add(c);
     }
}else{
     //the else part 
}
```

Comment: Rather than Count() > 0 you could use .Any(). Also, I think your || should be an &&

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will need this. Anyway, in case you often need default behavior for empty lists, you may create next extension method.

```
void Main()
{
    var elements = Enumerable.Range(0,20);
    elements.ForEachWithElse(x=>Console.WriteLine (x),
                            ()=>Console.WriteLine ("no elements at all"));

    elements.Take(0).ForEachWithElse(x=>Console.WriteLine (x),
                            ()=>Console.WriteLine ("no elements at all"));
}

public static class MyExtensions
{    
    public static void ForEachWithDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, Action<T> function, Action emptyBehaviour)
    {
        if(values.Any())
            values.ToList().ForEach(function);
        else 
            emptyBehaviour();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no foreach-else loop... If you need that functionality, either use a different type of loop (for-loop or maybe do-while-loop) or test for number of elements first.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an article](http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/.net-for-else) on how to implement something along the lines.

> It's your regular every day foreach on IEnumerable but allows you to
>   specify both a "loop-action" and an "else-action" where the latter is
>   executed after the loop unless you break the loop by returning false
>   from the former. It's a tad clumsier than Python but still useful

What you can do instead is to just check it being null/empty with an `if` test, and then do something in the `else` part.
However, when doing DB stuff, it's better to return an empty list when there are no result, instead of returning null.